# Store JSON data as a variable

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to store JSON data into a variable for later use. How do I store it, and is it possible to use the variable in another view controller, or do I have to do another request to fetch the data?

This is my code:

```
@IBAction func signinTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://XXXXXX/TestReqIOS.php") else {
        return
    }


    let email = txtEmail.text!
    let password = txtPassword.text!

    let data : Data = "loginSubmit=1&email=\(email)&password=\(password)&grant_type=password".data(using: .utf8)!
    var request : URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type");
    request.setValue(NSLocalizedString("lang", comment: ""), forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept-Language");
    request.httpBody = data

    print("Calling API")

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    // vs let session = URLSession.shared
    // make the request
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("error")
        }
        else if let response = response {
            print("response")

        }
        else if let data = data {
            print(data)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async { // Correct
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }
            print(String(data: responseData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Which will return:

```
{
  "id": "7",
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
  "email": "JohnDoe@text.com",
  "created": "2019-03-11",
  "modified": "2019-03-10",
}
```

Comment: What do you mean store it, like persist it to disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use a struct, such as in your case:

```
struct Data: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let first_name: String
    let last_name: String
    let email: String
    let created: Date
    let modified: Date
}
```

Then you create a variable of that struct where you will store it:

```
var dataVariable = [Data]()
```

Then you can do your URL call like:

```
 func getData(arr: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    let urlJSON = "URL"

    guard let url = URL(string: urlJSON) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {

            let getData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Data].self, from: data)
            self.dataVariable = getData


        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("error serializing json: \(jsonErr)")

        }
        completion(arr)

        }.resume()

}
```

Then you can access all of this from the dataVariable var. IF you do this in a Manager class you can access it from any ViewController.

To access:

```
let firstNameString = dataVariable[0].first_name
```

If there are not multiple trees of the same, then just make sure its:

```
let getData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Data.self, from: data)
```

Edit:

In your case put the above here:

```
  let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print("error")
    }
    else if let response = response {
        print("response")

    }
    else if let data = data {
         let getData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Data].self, from: data)
            self.dataVariable = getData // <- Just decode here
        print(data)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async { // Correct
        guard let responseData = data else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")
            return
        }
        print(String(data: responseData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? "")
    }
})
task.resume()
```

Comment: How do I send a post request with x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: @wiaK Do not ask an off-topic question as a comment. If the answer helped you and was right, accept it. If you have a different question, ask it as a new _question_.

Comment: @wiaK you should be able to take a look at my code and modify the getData function specifically the dataTask to suit your needs, compare and see what you would need to change, the important part of my Answer is the `let getData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Data].self, from: data)
            self.dataVariable = getData` that answers your question as to how to decode the data and get it into a variable that you can use.

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried to update my code and throw it around a little. When I did as instructed by you, I got `invalid Conversation from throwing funcion of type (...,...,...)` at `let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:"'` would you be able to help me?

Comment: @wiaK so you have the struct and the variable ready, and the only other difference in your code is the line `let getData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Data].self, from: data)
            self.dataVariable = getData` right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, in else if let data = data statement

Comment: @wiaK you may want to change your error catching to match my example above. It should work with the `do` statement. You should be able to just copy my example instead of your `let task = ` and do `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err)  in` instead.

Comment: but most importantly you need the `guard let data = data` and `do` + `catch` and that should allow you to use the `jsondecoder` safely.